# IDK whats wrong. It says input string is not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im using a detailsview control to show the details of the car from the row selected in gridview. It gets to the edit option but on clicking the update link it gives this error
Can any one help? Thanks in advance

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating1(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        int idd = Convert.ToInt32(DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text);
        TextBox gt = DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Controls[0] as ?TextBox;
        TextBox ma = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox mo = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox eng = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox cn = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox vin = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox am = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox cond = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox var = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox col = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox carnum = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;

        SqlDataAdapter SQLAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("update cars set geartype = '"+gt.Text+ "', make ='" +ma.Text + "',  model ='" + mo.Text + "', engnum ='" + eng.Text + "', chasisnum ='" + cn.Text + "', vin ='" + vin.Text + "', amount ='" + am.Text + "', Condition ='" + cond.Text + "', variant ='" + var.Text + "', color ='" + col.Text + "', carnum ='" + carnum.Text + "' where carid="+idd+"", con);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        SQLAdapter.Fill(DT);

        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: May be the `Convert.ToInt32` throws the Exception, try int.TryParse instead. It will be great if you take a look on [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: int idd = int.Tryparse(DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text); ?

Comment: Put a break point on that line and see what the string value is

Comment: It says tryparse takes only on argument

Comment: Can you show how to do it?

Comment: @DavidPilkington  value 0

Comment: It got resolved but now it says conversion failed while converting varchar to int. Can any one tell where am i going wrong